# PHP - Need Help Declaring And Using a Constant

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP. I've been looking at the documentation and am having a problem. I have a multi-page PHP site I am working on. I was having a problem with relative paths ([PHP Relative Path Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530390/php-relative-path-issues)) and was pointed to the following url([PHP include relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407664/php-include-relative-path)). I want to use something similar to the following code snippet in the post:

```
if (is_production()) {
    define('ROOT_PATH', '/some/production/path');
}
else {
    define('ROOT_PATH', '/root');
}
include ROOT_PATH . '/connect.php';
```

On what page do I add the define statement (index.php?) and how can I reference the ROOT_PATH on every subsequent page that has an include statement?

I tried adding the define statement to the index.php page but calling the ROOT_PATH on any other page results in: Use of undefined constant ROOT_PATH

Index.php: define('ROOT_PATH', '/some/production/path');
some other page: include_once(ROOT_PATH."/Library/API/database.inc.php");

Comment: you create a config file for all environment variable and add this file to all of your php files @FlyFish

Comment: @RyanVincent I tried adding the define statement to the index.php but it wasn't being recognized on any subsequent pages.

Comment: To expand on @parthmahida ... create a file called something like config.php and in there, add all of your configs, constants, etc ... then on each page, include the config.php file at the top.

Comment: @Spechal I'm stuck at the issue that started this. How do I reference the config file without using the complete absolute path Which is what I am trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong. I created a config.php file. I added in the following: return array('ROOT_PATH' => 'C:/Users/Me/Documents/app/site'); I added an include (include_once(ROOT_PATH."/Library/API/database.inc.php");
)to the file at the top of the page, but I get the following error: Notice: Use of undefined constant ROOT_PATH - assumed 'ROOT_PATH'

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possible (common) approaches:

Create files for each environment like `production.inc.php` and `development.inc.php` and include the one you need in your `index.php` by using your `is_production()` condition.

-- OR --

Create a single file that contains

```
if (is_production()) {
    define('ROOT_PATH', '/some/production/path');
} else {
    define('ROOT_PATH', '/root');
}
```

and then just include that single file to all your pages that need those constants.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear. I'm only looking to have a SINGLE define statement. My issue is that I can't figure out how to populate the 'ROOT_PATH' constant and then access it on other pages.

Comment: @FlyFish that's what I meant with the last sentence on my answer. Just do `include_once("config.inc.php");` on all the pages that needs to access the contant.

Answer (score 0):

I believe my issue was a SCOPING Issue. Although I went with @ parthmahida and @Spechal suggestion, there was still an issue. I ended up having to look at scoping to see it in the functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a file that will contain your environment configuration information and constants, it will always have to be relative to the script calling it.

```
<?php

// config.php
function is_production(){ // do something to return boolean }
if (is_production()) {
    define('ROOT_PATH', '/some/production/path');
}
else {
    define('ROOT_PATH', '/root');
}
```

...

```
<?php

// index.php
include 'config.php';
include ROOT_PATH . 'some-file.php';
// do stuff
```

...

```
<?php

// some-page.php
include 'config.php';
include ROOT_PATH . 'other-file.php';
// do stuff
```